# How to differentiate between assigning and declaring values from a function with multiple returns?

Tags: syntax, go

When retrieving multiple returns from a function, I get that you can declare variables for the values on the fly by using `:=` or assign the values to already existing variables by simply using `=`. My issue occurs when I want to assign one of the return values to an already existing variable while declaring a new variable for the other.

I have currently solved it by only assigning the values and declaring the required variables (`bar` in this case) beforehand, as in this snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func getFooAndBar() (foo string, bar string) {
    return "Foo", "Bar"
}

func main() {
    var foo = "default"
    var condition = true
    if condition {
        var bar string // Would like to avoid this step if possible
        foo, bar = getFooAndBar()
        fmt.Println(bar)
    }
    fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

If I use `:=` it fails to build due to:

> ./app.go:16: foo declared and not used

So, is it possible to somehow avoid the step declaring `bar` separately?

Comment: Because `:=` would create a new `foo` shadowing the other you can't use it here. What you have is the way to do it (`:=` is just a short cut after all).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you can't use the short variable declarations `":="` for redeclaring the `foo` variable, according to the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may
>   redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in
>   the same block with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank
>   variables is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a
>   multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a
>   new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

by eliminating  `./app.go:16: foo declared and not used`.

```
func main() {
    var foo = "default"
    var condition = true
    if condition {
        foo, bar := getFooAndBar()
        fmt.Println(bar) // prints: Bar
        fmt.Println(foo) // prints: Foo
        // _ = foo
    }
    fmt.Println(foo) // prints: default
}
```

in this case `foo` is declared in the `if` block, this declaration will **create a new variable** shadowing the original `foo` variable in the outer block, the redeclaration of `foo` will happen only if you have declared `foo` and redeclared it with multi-variable short declaration within the **same block**.

```
func main() {
    var foo = "default"     
    foo, bar := getFooAndBar()
    fmt.Println(bar) //prints: Bar
    fmt.Println(foo) //prints: Foo
}
```